# Correlation matrix and categorical variables

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data

I have the data frame `df`, of which I show the first few rows

```
age region    graduate salary
19  "North"   "no"     21000
25  "South"   "yes"    24000
23  "Center"  "yes"    23000
30  "South"   "no"     25000
```

where `region` can be "North", "Center" or "South" and `graduate` can be "yes" or "no". My goal is to perform the following analysis

```
library("corrplot")

df <- data.frame(age=c(19,25,23,30), region=c("North","South","Center","South"), graduate=c("no","yes","yes","no"), salary=c(21000,24000,23000,25000))
corrplot(cor(df), method='number')
```

but I get the following error:
`Error in cor(df) : 'x' must be numeric`.

What's the solution here?
Do I necessarily have to transform the original database into the following

```
age region-North region-Center region-South graduate-yes graduate-no salary
19       1            0             0            0           1       21000
25       0            0             1            1           0       24000
23       0            1             0            1           0       23000
30       0            0             1            0           1       25000
```

and then re-launch the code? Or can I operate directly in the method `corrplot`? The goal is to understand which variables influence `salary` the most.

Comment: I think instead of calculating the correlation, you can use Analysis of Variance (ANOVA) to know whether there is a difference in the mean salary across regions & graduates

Answer (score 0):

Correlation can be done only between numeric variables.
But in case of character variable following can be used for finding the correlation

*cor(rank(df$region), rank(df$graduate))*

Comment: If I replace in the data frame `region` with `rank(region)` and `graduate` with `rank(graduate)`, does it make sense to use function `cor` on the new data frame? I want to find a way to understand which variables affect the `salary` the most (see my question edited).

Comment: Another approach would be to use multiple regression, something like `lm(salary~age+region+graduate, df)`.

Comment: @LJG One approch that I think could help you out is , using Boruta package. Following is the link. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/select-important-variables-boruta-package/